# Best Data type for implementing IsDeleted column

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I want to add a new colum inside my users table named "Isdeleted", which can have only two values (Y,N). but what is the best dataType i can use for this column. i was thinking of just adding a varchar(1)? , but is there a better data type that can satisfy my need?
BR

Comment: How about a `BIT` ? Can only be `0` (=false), `1` (=true), or `NULL` (if allowed; undetermined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a `BIT` ? Can only be `0` (=false), `1` (=true), or `NULL` (if allowed; undetermined). Up to 8 `BIT` can be stored inside a single byte.

`VARCHAR(1)` is **horribly bad** because it will use 1-3 bytes of storage for each column.

If you want to use a character-based column type - by all means, use `CHAR(1)` (**not** varchar!). For just a single character, all the overhead (**at least** 2 byte per column!) of variable length storage is absolutely wasted.... this applies to all very short strings - things like 3-character ISO country or currency codes etc. - those are **best** stored in a fixed-with `CHAR(n)` datatype column

Comment: so i think CHAR will be better as i can inser Y OR N instead of 0 or 1

Comment: @JohnPeter: why is that better?? What more values other than `true` or `false` do you need for your `yes/no` columns?!?!?!?

Comment: yes i mean it is better to use Char(1) than BIT. as i can store chars like Y and N . while bit will allow to insert 0 or 1 only.

Comment: @JohnPeter: again ***WHY*** is storing `Y` or `N` better than storing 0 for false and 1 for true?? Be aware: if you have 32 such flags, using `BIT` you'll use 4 bytes - using `CHAR(1)` you'll use 32 bytes instead - for every single row! So in my opinion, **NO** it's **NOT** better to use `CHAR(1)` - **use `BIT`** - that's the most appropriate datatype here

Comment: but it will not be meangfull to store 0 , 1. as in this case i need to add another table to display what 0 and 1 stands for . while using Y and N can be more meangfull as Y stands for yes and N stand for no. what do u think?

Comment: I tried the BIT, but when i tried to add (1 or 0) inside i got the following error:- ""Invalid value for cell (row 42, column 17).

The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid.
.Net Framework Data Type: Boolean
Error Message: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.""

Comment: i define Bit ,, but it is a Bit confusing !!! since i can not inser 0,1 inside . i have instead to insert True & False. so Bit is a Bit confusing here .....

Comment: @JohnPeter: ***HOW*** are you trying to insert those values? Sounds like (a) you're doing something wrong there (`BIT` is typically a very simple datatype to use), and (b) sounds like material for a new question to ask here....