# Best DataType to store Isdeleted column

Tags: sql-server, datatable

I want to add a new column for Isdeleted which can have two values Yes Or No. so which data type is best to use:-

1. to use char(1) and store two values Y or N.
2. Bit. and store 1 or 0 . then i can on the application level to say that 1 means Yes and 0 means No.
3. varchar(3). and store Yes or No in the database , without the need to handle the display on the application level ?

i am confused abotu which dataTpe to use, and how to balance between storage used (best if Bit) and simpliciy (when using char(3)).

Best Regards

**EDIT**

i tried Bit but when i manually insert 1 or 0 inside the Sql server database i got the following error:-Invalid value for cell (row 42, column 17). The changed value in this cell was not recognized as valid. .Net Framework Data Type: Boolean Error Message: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.""

Comment: Your edited question is really a different question, and perhaps ought to be posted as such. I assume you're using the designer in VS? What happens when you type True or False? SQL Server has no BOOLEAN type, only a BIT type. I'm guessing the designer (or whatever) converts automatically between the SQL Server BIT type and the .NET Boolean type, and then between the .NET Boolean type to a .NET string which can be edited. Therefore, you need to type in a string value that can be converted to .NET Boolean, and the designer will convert the Boolean into the equivalent SQL Server BIT.

Comment: `bit not null` is best for simplicity as well as storage.

Comment: @john your edit is a different question ("How do I insert a value to a bit column?") - please post it as a new one, along with the code you are using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Data type for implementing IsDeleted column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17323470/best-data-type-for-implementing-isdeleted-column)

Comment: And do NOT post duplicates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best choice is (2) (the field should also be non-nullable), because the values are limited to 1 and 0. Generally, you want to handle display issues **only** at the application and not at any other.

As a trivial example of why display issues should be handled at the application level, you might need at some point to localize the UI to a different language with different terms for Yes and No.

Answer (score 1):

Use a boolean. This will make it clear to anyone reading your code (including you in 10 years - you'd be surprised!) that there are only 2 possible values.

Answer (score -1):

Depends on your choice

If you want to display as `Yes/No` then choice 1 ( you just need to manipulate the actual display in code)

But choice 2 is what I will go for.

Comment: @John, try inserting `true/false` in the bit column instead `0/1`

Comment: I disagree that choice 1 is ever better than choice 2 - if you need to manipulate the data for display anyway, you might as well manipulate a bit.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, still somewhat better than a single character; if you use winform app and use checkbox for the bit column ... checking/unchecking will insert true/false in that column automatically(a better case example).